# Img source set to data not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image, base64

I am trying to display an image that I fetch from a MySQL database (Image file read as Base64 and stored directly as a blob - I know there is debate as to how to store images on servers, however, this is how I am doing it). The JSFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/CkT7r/

The `src` is set dynamically at runtime, and the data retrieved via the web request is the whole text inside the quotation marks (Including the `data:` part).

Does anyone know why the image is failing to display?

Comment: Your data is corrupted, i.e. it is not valid base-64 encoded byte stream: `$ cat <your data> | base64 -d
base64: invalid input`

Comment: As Igor said. Either you are incorrectly using the string you got from the DB or you incorrectly stored it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = "https://yourdomain.com/image.png";

xhr.open(method, url, true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("Done")

        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( xhr.response );
        var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );

        document.getElementById("imgTest").src = imageUrl
    };
};
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer' // this is important
xhr.send();
```

Comment: How does this relate to the original question? Why are you introducing an AJAX call?

Comment: You obviously have not looked at the JS fiddle. The issue was with incorrect conversion from database format to base 64, hence why it wasn't rendering.